# Can I declare a field in JSON Schema as “JSON Schema”?

Tags: javascript, json, schema, jsonschema

A project of mine accepts “plugins”. These plugins need to provide a special JSON file which contains some meta information and also describes event objects with [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/index.html). For example:

```
{
    "name": "My component",
    "description": "My super awesome component",
    "documentation": "docs/main.md",
    "maintainer": "john.doe@example.com",
    "events": [{
        "name": "click",
        "description": "Occurs when the element is clicked.",
        "data": [{
                "name": "xPos",
                "description": "The horizontal position of the click.",
                "schema": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "minimum": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

This meta file will be validated against a JSON Schema. Now my question is, how could I validate the contents of the `events[0].data[0].schema` entry? In this case, the expected field is an integer, but it could be any other type, too. Is there a `"type":"schema"` or something similar defined in JSON Schema?

(For what it’s worth, I’m using [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) as validator.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be looking for the meta schema! The JSON Schema that describes a JSON Schema.

You can find them at http://json-schema.org/specification.html#meta-schemas

You want to reference the meta schema by it's $id like so.

```
{
  "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"
}
```

Using the above as your schema, and the below as your test data you want to fail, you can see it working using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net

```
{
  "type": "integer",
  "minimum": 0,
  "properties": ["a"],
}
```

You should consider however, that validation only asserts false because `properties` must be an object. **Unknown keywords are allowed and valid**, as is an empty object, or `true` or `false`, so if you were to change `properties` to `_properties` in my example, your schema would still be valid according to the meta schema.

---

Also relevant:

If you wanted to manually validate a schema is a valid schema, ajv allows you to do this easily! Documented at https://ajv.js.org/#api-validateschema

> `.validateSchema(Object schema) -> Boolean`
>
> Validates schema. This method should be used to validate schemas
>   rather than validate due to the inconsistency of uri format in JSON
>   Schema standard.
>
> By default this method is called automatically when the schema is
>   added, so you rarely need to use it directly.
>
> If schema doesn’t have $schema property, it is validated against draft
>   6 meta-schema (option meta should not be false).
>
> If schema has $schema property, then the schema with this id (that
>   should be previously added) is used to validate passed schema.
>
> Errors will be available at ajv.errors.

Comment: Thanks, but this means I cannot validate the `schema` nodes as part of the main schema … I must validate them as `"type":"object"` and later validate all known `schema` nodes separetely. Right?

Comment: If you're creating an overall schema for your structure (which includes a schema), you can reference the meta schema using $ref for where you would expect to see a schema. Am I understanding your situation correctly? You want to create a schema where part of it IS a JSON Schema?

Comment: Yes, a part of my schema is a schema. See my example above.

Comment: Ah, yes … `$ref` is the solution!